# Nextcord Slash command with button-function does not appear in the command menu

Tags: python, discord, nextcord, discord-buttons

I'm trying to create a slash command with buttons for my Discord bot. However, on Discord, in the menu bar for slash commands, the /button command does not appear.

I coded the command in a cog but there are no error messages.

To test whether the command works at all, I took it out of the Cog and inserted it into the main code (`main.py`). It worked.

So what's the problem that the slash command doesn't work in a cog?

I hope someone can do something with the code:

```
#main.py
import nextcord
from nextcord import interactions
from nextcord.ext import commands
import os

intents = nextcord.Intents.all()


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

initial_extensions = []

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        initial_extensions.append("cogs." + filename[:-3])
print(initial_extensions)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=nextcord.Status.online, activity=nextcord.Game('!help'))
    print("The Bot is now ready for use!")
    print("-----------------------------")
    for ext in initial_extensions:
        client.load_extension(ext)

testServerID = placeholder_serverID


@client.slash_command(guild_ids=[testServerID])
async def test(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("This is a test-Slash-command!")



client.run('BOTTOKEN')
```

Also here the code for the cog:

```
#UI.py

import nextcord
from nextcord import interactions
from nextcord.ext import commands

testServerID = placeholder_serverID


class UI(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    class Buttons(nextcord.ui.View):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.value = None

        @nextcord.ui.button(label='Button1', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
        async def button1(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message("Button1 was pressed!", ephemeral=False)
            self.value = True
            self.stop()

        @nextcord.ui.button(label='Button2', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.danger)
        async def button2(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message("Button2 was pressed!", ephemeral=False)
            self.value = False
            self.stop()

    @nextcord.slash_command(description="Test the buttons", guild_ids=[testServerID])
    async def button(self, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        view = self.Buttons()
        await interaction.response.send_message("Press a Button.", view=view)
        if view.value is None:
            await interaction.response.send_message("No button was pressed.")
        elif view.value:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Button1 was pressed!")
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Button2 was pressed!")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(UI(client))
```

I've already tried ChatGPT, but without success.I also looked for an example on the nextcord website, but they couldn't really help me either.

I think it might be because there are some changes between commands in a cog and commands that are not in a cog.
For example, `@client.slash_command` changes to `@nextcord.slash_command`.

I think one of these changes is responsible for the command not being displayed.
I am very grateful for any kind of help!